# Why styled-components not working in reactJs?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I checked a lot but the styled-components are not working in that react file.
Here is the sample code.
[image]

And this is output .... literally doing nothing.

[image]

Comment: React components must start with uppercase letters.

Comment: Always start your component name with a Captial letter.

Comment: Hello! Please add actual code that we can test and fiddle with. See [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

All react components must start with the capital letter.
Now it is working.

[image]

and now check the output!

[image]